# button to send multiple data to the database (php, ajax)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I send the data from the database to the screen with foreach.I do not see any results when I click the button.where do i make mistakes i ask you to help

```
 <table class="table">
   <thead class="thead-dark" align="center"  >

   <th >id</th>
   <th >EğitimAdı</th>
   <th >Adres</th>
   <th >Onay </th>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <form  id="form1" action="" method="post"> 
  <?php $i=1; foreach($dbb as $ac){ ; ?>
       <tr align="center" >  
           <td > <?php echo $ac[0]; ?> </td>
           <td > <?php echo $ac[1]; ?></td>
           <td   align="center"> <iframe width="360" height="115" src="<?php echo $ac[2]; ?>" frameborder="0" gesture="media" allow="encrypted-media" allowfullscreen  ></iframe></td>
            <td >
             <button type="button" value="<?php echo $ac[0]; ?>" id="gonder"  onclick="gonder('this.val()')">İzledim</button>  
            </td>
       </tr>
  <?php $i++; } ?>
  </form> <p></p>
 </tbody>

   </table>
```

gonder.js send to the database

```
   function gonder(deger){
        $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url:"isleme.php",
        data:deger,
        success:function(cevap) {
        $("p").text(cevap);
        }
        })

}
```

isleme.php to view the screen

```
<?php 
   $b=$_POST['deger'];
   echo $b;
    ?>
```

Comment: Can you please format your code correctly and format all your code as code (ctrl + k), it's difficult to read your post.

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: I am still very new in web software. I am trying to produce solutions from sample projects.

Answer (score 0):

First you're missing parentheses:

```
onclick="gonder" has to be onclick="gonder()"
```

Secondly variable "deger" is empty because #id doesn't exist, try changing to:

```
var deger = $("#gonder").val();
```

Comment: Unfortunately I did not apply what you wrote

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you are iterating and having same `id` for all the elements. Ideally id should be unique in each of the document.

You can do either of the below:

1. prepare and have unique id for each iterative element.
2. Try removing id element since you are not dependent on click using id.

Please let me know, if it helps?